# Failed to get the access_token from MS OneNote API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, onenote, onenote-api

We are facing issue while getting `access_token` or `refresh_token` from MS OneNote API, via PostMan.
Here is my request and the error (PFA screenshot):

[image]

I've used this url to get the code:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code
&client_id={client-id}
&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
&scope={scope}
```

Please let me know where the issue is

Comment: In step 2 ,I am fcing this issue .I refered the documents ::

Comment: Can you share specific instructions on how you repro'd this issue?

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible?